# How to add stretch for QGridLayout in PyQt5?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, qgridlayout

I created widgets in a grid-layout. The widgets are stretching based on the window. Is it possible to avoid the stretching and align them as shown in picture below? I created a code to achieve this, but I feel it is not a straightforward solution. If there are any better solutions to achieve this, please share them.

Grid layout result:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app =QApplication([])
window=QWidget()
GL=QGridLayout(window)
GL.addWidget(QPushButton('R1C1'),0,0)
GL.addWidget(QPushButton('R1C2'),0,1)
GL.addWidget(QPushButton('R2C1'),1,0)
GL.addWidget(QPushButton('R1C1'),1,1)
window.showMaximized()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Required Result:

[image]

My code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app =QApplication([])
window=QWidget()
VL=QVBoxLayout(window);HL=QHBoxLayout();VL.addLayout(HL)
GL=QGridLayout();HL.addLayout(GL)
GL.addWidget(QPushButton('R1C1'),0,0)
GL.addWidget(QPushButton('R1C2'),0,1)
GL.addWidget(QPushButton('R2C1'),1,0)
GL.addWidget(QPushButton('R1C1'),1,1)
HL.addStretch();VL.addStretch()
window.showMaximized()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It seems you already solved it, what's wrong with your version (besides its unnecessarily compressed and unreadable writing)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `QGridLaout` class doesn't have any simple convenience methods like `QBoxLayout.addStretch()` to do this. But the same effect can be achieved by adding some empty, stretchable rows/columns, like this:

```
GL.setRowStretch(GL.rowCount(), 1)
GL.setColumnStretch(GL.columnCount(), 1)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: working cool. this is what I expected. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using `.setSpacing()` and adding the below code:

```
MainLayout.addWidget(QLabel(''), MainLayout.rowCount(),0)
MainLayout.setRowStretch(MainLayout.rowCount(),1)
MainLayout.addWidget(QLabel(''),0,MainLayout.columnCount())
MainLayout.setColumnStretch(MainLayout.columnCount(),1)
```

`.setSpacing()` and `.setContentMargins()` will work beside this code, I don't know why, but it works very well.